# How to optimize Hibernate Query

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate

When requesting data fetch with the following parameters:(DaoLayer)

```
  List<JobsEntity> list = session.createQuery("from JobsEntity where cleanerEntity.id =:id and "
                + "cleanerEntity.franchiseId=clientEntity.franchiseId and deleted=false order by date desc")
                .setParameter("id", id).setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE).list();
```

Entity class JobsEntity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class JobsEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(nullable = false)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ClientEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private ClientEntity clientEntity;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = CleanerEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "cleaner_id")
private CleanerEntity cleanerEntity;

@Column(name = "allocation_date")
private Date date;
@Column(name = "end_date")
private Date endDate;

@Column(name = "optional_data")
private String optionalData;
@Column(name = "ntu")
private boolean ntu;
@Column(name = "deleted")
private boolean deleted;
```

I tried to write a native query

```
List<JobsEntity> list = session.createSQLQuery("Select * from jobs where cleaner_id =:id")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(JobsEntity.class))
                .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE).list();
```

And then create stream

Also try to use Creteria

```
 List<JobsEntity> list = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cleanerEntity.id", id))
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(JobsEntity.class))
                    .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
                    .list();
```

It takes a very long time now while it get info from db

-- Have you tried to use indicies on db Site for the columns in your WHERE clause?
Yes
-- Have you enabled the sql debug log to print all generated queries for further analysis?
No
-- Further, about how many records do we talk about?
20-30 for each

Comment: Have you tried to use indicies on db Site for the columns in your WHERE clause? Further, about how many records do we talk about? Maybe try to use Pagination if you don’t need all records at once. Another thing: Have you enabled the sql debug log to print all generated queries for further analysis?

Comment: how many fields do ClientEntity and CleanerEntity have?

Comment: ClientEntity 62 fields, CleanerEntity 59 fields

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are:

1. Declare the query as an **annotated name query** because at startup, during the CDI scanning, hibernate builds the metadata cache and exection plans making the execution much more faster.
2. Use the FetchType.LAZY to get generated a single JOIN native query.
3. On your query set `QueryHints.HINT_READONLY` to `true` to prevent hibernate from instantiate all the dirty flag and state tracking infrastructure.